# Is it possible to find a non-zero solution of an ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

Is it possible to solve the 4th-order ode analytically?

```
op[r_] = (D[#, {r, 2}] - 1/r*D[#, r]) &;

DSolve[{op[r][op[r][f[r]]] == 0, f[b] == 0, f'[b] == 0, (f''[r] - 1/r*f'[r] - f[r]/(c - 1) /. r -> (1 + b)) == 0, (f'''[r] - 1/r*f''[r] + 1/r^2*f'[r] /. r -> (1 + b)) == 0}, f[r], r]
```

I am using v11 in which `DSolve` returns a trivial solution `f[r] -> 0` only.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For general values of $b$ and $c$, the trivial solution is indeed the only solution.  However, there are special values of $b$ and $c$ which can yield non-trivial solutions.

To find these, we can start by telling Mathematica to find the general solution to the ODE:

```
soln = DSolve[{op[r][op[r][f[r]]] == 0}, f, r]

(* {f -> Function[{r}, (r^2 C[1])/2 - (r^2 C[2])/4 + (r^4 C[3])/4 + C[4] + 1/2 r^2 C[2] Log[r]]} *)
```

We can then look at the boundary conditions and see what they imply about the coefficients `C[i]`.  We do this by storing the vanishing quantities in a list `BCs`;  the actual equations are then `BCs == 0`.

```
BCs = { f[b], 
        f'[b], 
       (f''[r] - 1/r*f'[r] - f[r]/(c - 1) /. r -> (1 + b)), 
       (f'''[r] - 1/r*f''[r] + 1/r^2*f'[r] /. r -> (1 + b))};
quants = BCs /. First[soln]
```

The quantities in `quants` are four linear combinations of the coefficients `C[1]`, `C[2]`, `C[3]`, and `C[4]`, all of which must vanish.  We can think of this set of simultaneous equations as the result of a matrix $M$  multiplying the vector $\vec{v} = \{C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4\}$.  From basic results in linear algebra, we know that the only way for there to be a non-trivial solution for $\vec{v}$ is for the matrix $M$ to have a non-zero determinant.  So we construct this matrix and take its determinant:

```
mat = Outer[Coefficient, quants, {C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4]}];
Simplify[Det[mat]]

(* -((b (1 + b) (-3 + 2 b + 4 c + 2 (1 + b)^2 Log[b] - 2 (1 + b)^2 Log[1 + b]))/(-1 + c)) *)
```

This implies that the trivial solution is the only solution to the ODE unless this last quantity (in terms of the constants $b$ and $c$) is zero, which occurs when $b = 0$, $b = -1$, or
$$
c = \frac{3 - 2b + 2 (1+b)^2 \ln( (1+b)/b )}{4}.
$$

Comment: thank you very much, but the question is actually not solved completely... I tried `csoln = Solve[Det[mat] == 0, c] // Simplify` and substituted the special `c` in the original system but the solution still includes one unknown constant. Please see `DSolve[{op[r][op[r][f[r]]] == 0, f[b] == 0, f'[b] == 0, (f''[r] - 1/r*f'[r] - f[r]/(c - 1) /. {r -> (1 + b), csoln[[1, 1]]}) == 0, (f'''[r] - 1/r*f''[r] + 1/r^2*f'[r] /. r -> (1 + b)) == 0}, f[r], r]`, it also gives a warning _Unable to resolve some of the arbitrary constants _

Comment: Yes, there will be unknown constants in the solution.  They should correspond to the overall normalization of the solution;  if $f(x)$ is a solution then so is $\alpha f(x)$ for any $\alpha$, because the equation is linear.

Comment: Prof. Seifert thanks a lot! Your comment is plausible. But with `Det[mat]==0` we should have non-zero solution for `C[i]`, however, when substituting the eigenvalue `c` back to `mat`, which represents vanishing quantities for the b.c.s, I got zero solution... Please try `csoln = Solve[Det[mat] == 0, c]` and `LinearSolve[mat/.First[csoln], {0, 0, 0, 0}]`

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat  different way is as follows.

```
s = DSolve[{op[r][op[r][f[r]]] == 0, f[b] == 0, f'[b] == 0}, f, r]
```

> `{{f -> Function[{r}, (1/( 4 b^2))(-b^4 C[1] + 2 b^2 r^2 C[1] - r^4 C[1] + b^4 C[2] -  b^2 r^2 C[2] - b^4 C[2] Log[b] - r^4 C[2] Log[b] +  2 b^2 r^2 C[2] Log[r])]}}`

```
Resolve[Exists[{C[1], C[2]},Simplify[f'[1 + b]/(1 + b)^2 - f''[1 + b]/(1 + b) + f'''[1 + b] /. 
  s[[1]]]==0 && Simplify[-(f[1 + b]/(-1 + c)) - f'[1 + b]/(1 + b) + f''[1 + b] /. 
  s[[1]]]==0&& C[1]^2 + C[2]^2 != 0], Reals]
```

> `b > 0 && c ==  1/4 (3 - 2 b - 2 Log[b] - 4 b Log[b] - 2 b^2 Log[b] +  2 Log[1 + b] + 4 b Log[1 + b] + 2 b^2 Log[1 + b])`

The main difference from Michael Seifert's answer consists in the use of quantifiers instead of linear algebra. This way is more automatical.

Comment: One could also start from `DSolve[{op[r][op[r][f[r]]] == 0, f, r]`.